# Enable event windowActivated (JFrame) from JPanel

Tags: java, events, jframe, jpanel, windowlistener

I have this problem: I'm builting a game. I'm trying check if the missionA is complete, pass to MissionB.

I have a StageClass (extends JFrame), this:

```
public class Stage extends JFrame {
  Scene missionOne;
public Stage(){
  //Code
  missionOne=new Scene();
  add(missionOne);
  addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter(){         
        public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
            checkMissionState();
        }
    });
}

private void checkMissionState(){
        if(missionOne.complete()){          
            //ChangeMission
        }
    }
}
```

In the scene class:

```
public class Scene extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
   //Allcode
   public boolean complete(){
     boolean sw=false;
     //Verify a list of conditions
     return sw;
   }
```

When mission is complete, I don't get execute checkMissionState(). The reason is that the focus in this moment is Scene. I tried windowLostFocus, windowDeactivated and doesn't execute too.

I can get a solution sending on the screen a JOptionPane message from complete()

```
public class Scene extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
  //Allcode

   public boolean complete(){
     boolean sw=false;
     //Verify a list of conditions 
    if(sw) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mission is complete");
      return sw;
}
```

Works. But this quit Jugagability at Game.

I'm searching a form of execute checkMissionState() in JFrame without                            sending JOptionPane message.

How could do it?

Comment: Why would activating a window change the state of the game? If the mission was complete before the window lost focus then it will still be complete if the window regains focus. So your game play logic needs to check when the mission is complete, not a WindowListener.

Comment: When I add the scene missionOne focus Lost
I'm trying to use **windowActivated** because are ten (10) missions, ten objects of SceneClass that must be add or remove from JFrame

Answer (score 0):

In your **Scene** class, you can implement **FocusListener** interface and override the following methods.

```
@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe){
    System.out.println("Focus gained in JPanel");
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){
    System.out.println("Focus lost in JPanel");
}
```

Add following statement in your **Scene** class constructor.

```
addFocusListener(this);
```

Not knowing what action you performed when focus lost or gained, you can implement your appropriate game action against focusLost and focusGained events.

Comment: I would remove the JPanel from JFrame and add a new JPanel in JFrame.
Can I do that from JPanel that is out?...

Comment: Not sure what you mean Panel that is out. But you can add JPanel to container dynamically. After you add each panel don't forget to revalidate() the parent panel.